# bash if операция сравнения not found

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
    x="0"
    count="2"
    if ["$count" -eq "$x"]
    then
    echo "s123"
    fi
```

error:

```
4: 123.sh: [2: not found
```

В интернете много чего находил и пробовал, но почему то у меня не получается, будьте добры подскажите в чём проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` — это программа (см. примечание), которая находится в каталоге `/usr/bin`:

```
$ which [
/usr/bin/[
```

а программы `[2` у вас в системе явно нет (получается такое имя после подстановки переменной — `["$count"` → `[2`).

синтаксис, понимаемый программой `[`, подразумевает, что окончанием выражения будет `" ]"` (пробел, затем закрывающая квадратная скобка).

т.е., вам просто пробелы надо добавить (внутри квадратных скобок).

вместо:

```
["$count" -eq "$x"]
```

написать:

```
[ "$count" -eq "$x" ]
```

---

#### примечание:

вообще, конечно, программа `bash` имеет внутреннюю команду `test`, а `[` рассматривает как её псевдоним, т.е., не использует внешнюю программу `/usr/bin/[`, но поведение этой программы эмулирует точно.

Comment: Можно ещё `$ man test` посмотреть.

Comment: и даже `$ man [`

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
x="0"
count="2"
if [ $count -eq $x ] # [ и $count не должны быть написаны слитно,
                     # ну и в кавычки повторно необязательно переменные помещать.
then
  echo "s123"
fi
```